# Placing Fruits in line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have :

- $2$ apples
- $2$ oranges
- one pineapple

*Apples,oranges are indistinguables*

First of all I want to find the total number of possibilities so I think we are placing the pineapple at a fixed place and then permute the apples/oranges so : 
$$
\binom{4}{2} \cdot 5
$$

Now if I want to have all the possibilities **and** considering arrangement and its inverse (starting from the end) the same arrangement

For example : Apple-Orange-PineApple-Apple-Orange and Orange-Apple-PineApple-Orange-Apple

I was thinking we need to subtract the cases we have count several times
So the only case we will have 2 same arrangement is when the pineapple is a the center so I was thinking all the possibilities will be:

[image]

Comment: I think you have already posted this problem, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499749/placing-vegetables-in-skewer).  That version was closed because the question lacked clarity.  This one is not clear either.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to first count the patterns with the pineapple away from the center.  Remember you need to divide that count by $2$ since you count each of those twice.  Then count those with the pineapple in the center.  You appear to believe that there are two such patterns..which two patterns do you see?

Comment: Can you please clearly state what you are trying to find along with some context.

Comment: @lulu can you give me some advice on what to explain more or less  to make myself clearer , I am trying my best

Comment: You only need to consider the cases where the pineapple is in slots $1,2,3$. After that any arrangement you try to make will be counting inverses of ones you have already counted

Comment: I think I sorted out what you are asking.  "Count the number of ways to arrange these five fruit in a line, where we say that two arrangements coincide if they differ only in their direction (right to left vs. left to right).  Thus $APOOA$ is understood to be the same arrangement as $AOOPA$.  "   Have I got that right?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, you need to divide your first term by $2$ to account for the symmetry.  But I don't understand the second term.

Comment: @lulu yes, i understood why i need to divide by 2 now but for me there is only 2 possibilities when the pineapple is in the middle

Comment: Which two patterns do you see?  I see three:  $AAPOO, AOPOA, AOPAO$.

Comment: @lulu i see there is some mathematical link that you have find 3 or simply writing down and see ?

Comment: With so few patterns, I found it easier to just write them down.

Comment: Its not simply ( 2 among 4) / 2 ? So there is 15 possibilities if I understood right no ?

Comment: To be clear:  With $P$ in the middle,  there are only four ways to populate the first two slots, $AA, OO, OA, AO$.  $AA$ and $OO$ lead to the same (unique) arrangement.   If we take $OA$ then the last two slots are similarly $AO$ or $OA$.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, though I do get $15$ as the final answer:  as $2\times \binom 42+3=15$.

Comment: In general, you should edit an existing question rather than ask a new, essentially identical one. (Given the interaction above, I don't think it is correct to close this question as a duplicate of the original.)

Comment: Note:  for whatever reason I left $OAPAO$ off the list with $P$ in the middle.  Hence my count was off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways to create a "word" out of the letters $A,A,O,O,P$ is $$\frac{5!}{2!2!} = 30$$

Of these, only two of them are their own inverse: $AOPOA$ and $OAPAO$. This means the other $28$ have been double counted, so after dividing by $2$ and adding back the two whose inverse is the same we get $14+2=16$ ways.

This answer is also supported utilizing [Burnside's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma), letting $|G|=2$:

$$\frac12 \left( 30 + 2\right) = 16$$ where the $2$ comes from the number of ways that the "word" stays the same if we flip it

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot !